# WebThread JavaScriptCore crash - what this crash report means

Tags: ios, crash-reports, javascriptcore

I need help in understanding this crash log from a test user. 
I did not write any JavaScriptCore related code in my app.

I still don't know how to reproduce this crash. Any insights about this problem would be helpful to me in finding this problem.

Thanks,

P.S
My app is using Admob mediation. I don't know if it has some relation about this.

```
Incident Identifier: 7B6EFFFF-4D55-48AE-8FE8-A55590405F0A
CrashReporter Key:   ef1ad783966254a93308221f30f17134c95879f7
Hardware Model:      iPad5,3
Process:             ???? [2325]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/16AE72E1-A8C8-45D9-955F-A6F96FCCE800/????.app/????
Identifier:          ????
Version:             3.75.14 (3.75)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-05-16 10:36:50.459 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-05-16 10:00:10.481 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.3 (12F69)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000bbadbeef
Triggered by Thread:  4

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197080e0c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197080c84 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852fb720 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852f9674 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852252d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   GraphicsServices                0x000000018e9036f8 GSEventRunModal + 164
6   UIKit                           0x0000000189deafa8 UIApplicationMain + 1484
7   ClockXtrm                       0x000000010004f668 main (main.m:17)
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000196f82a04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197080c24 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196f65e6c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196f57998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197080e48 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000196f63f3c _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 252
2   MediaToolbox                    0x000000018780cb48 fpa_AsyncMovieControlThread + 1952
3   CoreMedia                       0x0000000185b5f9ac figThreadMain + 244
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137dc4 _pthread_body + 160
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137d20 _pthread_start + 156
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197080e0c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197080c84 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852fb720 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852f9674 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852252d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000184d06890 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 436
6   Foundation                      0x0000000186245db4 __NSThread__main__ + 1068
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137dc4 _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137d20 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4 Crashed:
0   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186c3d58c WTFCrash + 72
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186c3d580 WTFCrash + 60
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b3df1c JSC::JSLock::DropAllLocks::DropAllLocks(JSC::VM*) + 268
3   WebCore                         0x000000019391fd54 SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*) + 128
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185347f68 ___forwarding___ + 436
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018524acc8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 88
6   WebCore                         0x000000019395fda0 WebCore::DOMWindow::removeAllEventListeners() + 176
7   WebCore                         0x0000000193943694 WebCore::Document::removeAllEventListeners() + 28
8   WebCore                         0x00000001939424b8 WebCore::Document::~Document() + 216
9   WebCore                         0x0000000193d9a12c WebCore::HTMLDocument::~HTMLDocument() + 8
10  WebCore                         0x0000000193942114 WebCore::Node::~Node() + 152
11  WebCore                         0x0000000193941f0c WebCore::HTMLHtmlElement::~HTMLHtmlElement() + 8
12  WebCore                         0x00000001939b7874 WebCore::JSNodeOwner::finalize(JSC::Handle<JSC::Unknown>, void*) + 420
13  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186895498 JSC::WeakBlock::sweep() + 108
14  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018681c978 JSC::WeakSet::sweep() + 28
15  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018681c8fc JSC::MarkedBlock::sweep(JSC::MarkedBlock::SweepMode) + 24
16  JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018681b58c JSC::MarkedAllocator::allocateSlowCase(unsigned long) + 296
17  WebCore                         0x0000000194010c1c WebCore::JSDOMWrapper* WebCore::createWrapper<WebCore::JSHTMLCanvasElement, WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement>(WebCore::JSDOMGlobalObject*, WebCore::HTMLCanvasElement*) + 588
18  WebCore                         0x0000000194007a3c WebCore::createJSHTMLWrapper(WebCore::JSDOMGlobalObject*, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::HTMLElement>) + 312
19  WebCore                         0x0000000193887348 WebCore::toJSNewlyCreated(JSC::ExecState*, WebCore::JSDOMGlobalObject*, WebCore::Element*) + 56
20  WebCore                         0x00000001938871a4 WebCore::jsDocumentPrototypeFunctionCreateElement(JSC::ExecState*) + 376
21  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96fac llint_entry + 26156
22  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
23  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
24  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
25  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
26  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
27  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
28  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
29  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
30  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
31  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b969d8 llint_entry + 24664
32  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
33  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
34  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
35  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
36  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b96974 llint_entry + 24564
37  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b90760 callToJavaScript + 304
38  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186afeac4 JSC::JITCode::execute(JSC::VM*, JSC::ProtoCallFrame*) + 44
39  JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001868695e0 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 416
40  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186940924 JSC::boundFunctionCall(JSC::ExecState*) + 532
41  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186b908e8 callToNativeFunction + 312
42  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186869624 JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 484
43  JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186995738 JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&, JSC::JSValue*) + 88
44  WebCore                         0x0000000193a932a4 WebCore::JSCallbackData::invokeCallback(JSC::JSValue, JSC::MarkedArgumentBuffer&, bool*) + 580
45  WebCore                         0x00000001940dd988 WebCore::JSRequestAnimationFrameCallback::handleEvent(double) + 176
46  WebCore                         0x0000000194423de4 WebCore::ScriptedAnimationController::serviceScriptedAnimations(double) + 424
47  WebCore                         0x0000000193c2462c WebCore::DisplayRefreshMonitor::displayDidRefresh() + 452
48  QuartzCore                      0x000000018971a298 CA::Display::DisplayLinkItem::dispatch() + 28
49  QuartzCore                      0x000000018971a130 CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long) + 320
50  IOKit                           0x00000001864f546c IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 372
51  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852e6dc0 __CFMachPortPerform + 176
52  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852fba50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
53  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852fb9b0 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 432
54  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852f9930 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
55  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852252d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
56  WebCore                         0x0000000193904890 RunWebThread(void*) + 464
57  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137dc4 _pthread_body + 160
58  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137d20 _pthread_start + 156
59  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709b498 __select + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000185301124 __CFSocketManager + 668
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137dc4 _pthread_body + 160
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137d20 _pthread_start + 156
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 6 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709b078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197136f28 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000196080d5c std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 136
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186982574 JSC::BlockAllocator::waitForDuration(std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000l> >) + 176
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186819588 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 76
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186814b9c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137dc4 _pthread_body + 160
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137d20 _pthread_start + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 7 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709b078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197136f28 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000196080cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 52
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186ac2edc JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 152
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186ac2f80 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186814b9c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137dc4 _pthread_body + 160
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137d20 _pthread_start + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 8 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709b078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197136f28 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x0000000196080cac std::__1::condition_variable::wait(std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 52
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186ac2edc JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 152
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186ac2f80 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 88
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186814b9c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137dc4 _pthread_body + 160
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137d20 _pthread_start + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 9 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197080e0c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197080c84 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852fb720 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852f9674 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852252d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   WebCore                         0x00000001939389ac WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 284
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186814b9c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137dc4 _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137d20 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 10 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709b078 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197136f28 _pthread_cond_wait + 620
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001868197bc WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 76
3   WebCore                         0x000000019448e32c std::__1::unique_ptr<WTF::Function<void ()>, std::__1::default_delete<WTF::Function<void ()> > > WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessage()::'lambda'(WTF::Function<void ()> const&)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessage()::'lambda'(WTF::Function<void ()> const&)&&, double) + 96
4   WebCore                         0x0000000193a00ff8 WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 220
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000186814b9c WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 20
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137dc4 _pthread_body + 160
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137d20 _pthread_start + 156
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 11 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197080e0c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197080c84 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852fb720 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852f9674 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001852252d0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x0000000183ca102c GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 160
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x0000000183c93a0c CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 116
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137dc4 _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197137d20 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134ef4 thread_start + 0

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001971352d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001971352d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001971352d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001971352d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001971352d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001971352d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019709bc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001971352d8 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197134eec start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x00001f0000001f00   x2: 0x000000019aeb1ee0   x3: 0x0000000103b2c82c
    x4: 0x0000000103b2c828   x5: 0x0000000103b2c900   x6: 0x000000000000000a   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x00000000bbadbeef   x9: 0x0000000000000000  x10: 0x0000000000001f00  x11: 0x0000000000001f00
   x12: 0x0000000186b96978  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000003  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x00000001970c80fc  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000103b2c9a8
   x20: 0x0000000170a786c0  x21: 0x0000000170a786c0  x22: 0x000000018a59aedd  x23: 0x000000019a8ebb20
   x24: 0x000000019a8eba10  x25: 0x000000018a58a2d0  x26: 0x0000000103b2cfa0  x27: 0x000000000000a740
   x28: 0x0000000000000002  fp: 0x0000000103b2cac0   lr: 0x0000000186c3d584
    sp: 0x0000000103b2c9a0   pc: 0x0000000186c3d58c cpsr: 0x60000000
```

Comment: I also use AdMob mediation, and also get this crash.  I am still getting the crash from iOS 9.3.x users.  So if it is a WebKit bug, it still isn't fixed as of iOS 9.3.1

Answer (score 5):

This crash is a result of [bug in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=139654). It was [fixed at 06/05/15](http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/185268). iOS 9 was released at 09/09/15, so most probably this bug is already fixed in last iOS version. Although it still affects iOS 8, and there is no straightforward workaround.

Comment: I can confirm that this still occurs on iOS 9 (according to Fabric logs)

Comment: Yeah i also got Fabric crash logs of this JavaScriptCore WTFCrash on iOS 9.3.4.

Comment: still remaining in ios 11

Comment: We was not aware of this problem until iOS 11.4.3. Now we have high user complains amount about the app crash. Crash happens in webThread, in DropAllLocks. In my case the crash is reproducible. It related to web ads (no ads - no crashes).

Comment: We also face the same problem in iOS 11+ and it only happens when user is online and page contains optional content that is retrieved from the web. We run a magazine for iPad so most of the content is bundled, but we also serve some extra videos only when user is online..

The exact same code works excellent in pre-iOS 11 devices!!

Comment: are you all using YoutubePlayer by any chance ?