# WebCore crash, iOS 11, related to UIWebView scripts. (JSC::JSLock::DropAllLocks::DropAllLocks)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Tons of crashes start happening on iOS 11 in the apps using `UIWebView` and showing rich content, like ads or videos. It was a similar problem in 2015, which then was fixed (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315696/webthread-javascriptcore-crash-what-this-crash-report-means)). Now it re-appears again.

I saw some similar, but I still decided to post my problem, this is *not a duplicate*, but aggregated information about this crash from different, seems not-related at glance sources. Hope it will help to **bring attention and solve the case faster**. I also want **to give bounty on the solution**, so please don't remove this question.

1. My case - `UIWebView` in native Obj-C app. The problem only appears to happens in free version, which serves the ads. The date when it starts - July, 22. It was no app update at the time. All crashes in iOS 11 only. Thousands of them. Crash stack:

> Crashed: WebThread 0  JavaScriptCore                 0x188a8d464
>   JSC::JSLock::DropAllLocks::DropAllLocks(JSC::VM&) + 176 1 
>   JavaScriptCore                 0x188a8d438
>   JSC::JSLock::DropAllLocks::DropAllLocks(JSC::VM&) + 132 2  WebCore
>   0x1897d5cec SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation*) + 360 3  CoreFoundation
>   0x18163c2d4 ***forwarding*** + 624 4  CoreFoundation
>   0x18152241c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92 5  WebCore
>   0x189806588 WebCore::DOMWindow::removeAllEventListeners() + 412 6 
>   WebCore                        0x1897eee3c
>   WebCore::Document::removeAllEventListeners() + 32 7  WebCore
>   0x1897ed47c WebCore::Document::~Document() + 544 8  WebCore
>   0x18a533860 WebCore::HTMLDocument::~HTMLDocument() + 12 9  WebCore
>   0x1897ed11c WebCore::Node::~Node() + 384 10 WebCore
>   0x1898538bc WebCore::HTMLLinkElement::~HTMLLinkElement() + 12 11
>   JavaScriptCore                 0x188a69a5c void
>   JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::specializedSweep(JSC::FreeList*,
>   JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::EmptyMode,
>   JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::SweepMode,
>   JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::SweepDestructionMode,
>   JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::ScribbleMode,
>   JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::NewlyAllocatedMode,
>   JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::MarksMode,
>   JSC::JSDestructibleObjectDestroyFunc const&) + 196 12 JavaScriptCore
>   0x188a6846c void
>   JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::finishSweepKnowingHeapCellType(JSC::FreeList*,
>   JSC::JSDestructibleObjectDestroyFunc const&)::'lambda'()::operator()()
>   const + 348 13 JavaScriptCore                 0x188a67fa4 void
>   JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::finishSweepKnowingHeapCellType(JSC::FreeList*,
>   JSC::JSDestructibleObjectDestroyFunc const&) + 320 14 JavaScriptCore
>   0x188a67e58
>   JSC::JSDestructibleObjectHeapCellType::finishSweep(JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle&,
>   JSC::FreeList*) + 32 15 JavaScriptCore                 0x1887e997c
>   JSC::MarkedBlock::Handle::sweep(JSC::FreeList*) + 372 16
>   JavaScriptCore                 0x1887e0064
>   JSC::IncrementalSweeper::sweepNextBlock() + 132 17 JavaScriptCore
>   0x1881c27fc JSC::IncrementalSweeper::doWork() + 72 18 JavaScriptCore
>   0x188aad864
>   JSC::JSRunLoopTimer::timerDidFireCallback(**CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) +
>   76 19 CoreFoundation                 0x1815dfaa8
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 28 20 CoreFoundation                 0x1815df76c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 864 21
>   CoreFoundation                 0x1815df010 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 248
>   22 CoreFoundation                 0x1815dcb60 __CFRunLoopRun + 2168 23
>   CoreFoundation                 0x1814fcda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
>   24 WebCore                        0x1897c02d4 RunWebThread(void*) +
>   592 25 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18125d220 _pthread_body + 272
>   26 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18125d110 _pthread_body + 290 27
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18125bb10 thread_start + 4

2. [React Native IOS 11.3 - 11.4 Error: JavaScriptCore JSC::JSLock::DropAllLocks::DropAllLocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51474380/react-native-ios-11-3-11-4-error-javascriptcore-jscjslockdropalllocksdr). It seems that embedded Video Widget causes the same problem, also only iOS 11. The React Native platform seems unrelated, because the problem happens also in native Obj-C apps.
3. [Javascript core crash when using YouTube iframe player in UIWebView in iOS 11.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788390/javascript-core-crash-when-using-youtube-iframe-player-in-uiwebview-in-ios-11-3). YouTube iframe player causes the same problem. Again, all starts iOS 11.

This is huge problem, please advise and help us solve this. Thanks!